# Machine ID Code in C++

Tags: c++

I tried [this](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/177795-cmingwwmi-how-to-get-machine-uuid-in-c/) because I want to learn how to grab a machine unique ID.
I need it because I'm gonna code a program that reads the machineid and compares it to a specific one.
I edited the code(in the end, the code that prints the Machine ID) to this:

```
string MachineID;
MachineID = vtProp.bstrVal;
if (MachineID == vtProp.bstr)
```

but it only gives me this [error](http://gyazo.com/c143ed3457cbbb23f0e26ada10d26e06).
How would I make my HWID variable be set to the value of vtProp.bstrVal, then compare it with vtProp.bstrVal? I've googled for some hour now, can't seem to get it fixed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `=` is assignment, `==` is equality comparison. *but*, if these are not "smart" string classes (Like CComBSTR), you need to use string comparison functions.

Comment: oh, i mean that, sorry. But that doesnt work. Here is the error: http://gyazo.com/c143ed3457cbbb23f0e26ada10d26e06                      Oh, okay. Ill google that!

Comment: You need to convert `vtProp.bstr` to a `std::string` type, before comparing.  Only compare variables of the same type.

Comment: @Motherflufferr Well, you're expected to [give us](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6040858) a concise [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here, to get help on diagnosing your question, instead of posting obscure links!

Comment: Tried to convert vtProp.bstrVal to a string using this

    string HWID;
  
 ostringstream convert;

 convert << vtProp.bstrVal;

 HWID = convert.str();
 
    cout << HWID << endl;

But I get random numbers every time, like [this](http://gyazo.com/93a031f0a0e3d49c32b44a983c6f0872) and [this](http://gyazo.com/1cf864503ec010fa3c9612e460a1aebc). Why?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Simple syntax error - you've used `=`, which is assignment, instead of `==`, which is comparison.

Because c++ accepts nonboolean types in `if` statements, the code `if(variable = value)` is acceptable to the compiler, which tries to assign `MachineID` the value of `vtProp.bstr`, which causes your error due to type mismatch.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It was a typo in the post, sorry! :D